# How to navigate to home page change screen size in Angular 4?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm building a website with angular 4 and asp.net.

When you enter the website, you can see the home page fit to mobile size (which is what I want).

[image: home page]

then when I navigate to the orders page, it looks like this:

[image: orders page]

orders page

[image: menu: select orders page]

but when I navigate back to the home page again from the orders page, it changes the screen and does not fit to mobile at all.

[image: menu: select home page]

[image: home page doesn't fit to mobile screen any more]

**Code:**

app.component.html

```
<app-nav_mobile></app-nav_mobile>
<app-header></app-header>
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet> </router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

nav_mobile.component.html

```
    <div id="preloader" class="signature-dierk">
    <div id="status"></div>
</div>
<!-- end : preloader -->
<!-- mobile only navigation : starts -->
<nav class="mobile-nav signature-dierk">
    <ul class="slimmenu">
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home page</a></li>
        <li><a [routerLink]="['/order']">orders</a></li>
        <li><a href="checkout.html">checout </a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">producst</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<!-- mobile only navigation : ends -->
```

home.component.html

```
<section class="mastwrap signature-dierk">
<div class="inner-wrap">

    <section class="intro07 signature-dierk">

        <div id="rev_slider_3_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullscreen-container">
            <!-- START REVOLUTION SLIDER 4.6.5 fullscreen mode -->
            <div id="rev_slider_3_1" class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner">
                <ul>
                    <!-- SLIDE  -->
                    <li data-transition="slidedown" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1200" data-saveperformance="off">
                        <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                        <img data-no-retina alt="" title="" src="/dist/assets/images/bg1.jpg" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                        <!-- LAYERS -->
                        <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption featured-caption-one font3bold black lft ltb tp-resizeme"
                             data-x="center" data-hoffset="0"
                             data-y="center" data-voffset="0"
                             data-speed="600"
                             data-start="600"
                             data-easing="easeInOutQuad"
                             data-splitin="none"
                             data-splitout="none"
                             data-elementdelay="0.1"
                             data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                             data-endspeed="800"
                             data-endeasing="easeInOutQuad">
                            <span class="font3bold black">logo </span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!-- SLIDE  -->
                    <li data-transition="slidedown" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1200" data-saveperformance="off">
                        <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                        <img data-no-retina alt="" title="" src="/dist/assets/images/bg2.jpg" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                        <!-- LAYERS -->
                        <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption featured-caption-two font3light white lft ltb tp-resizeme"
                             data-x="center" data-hoffset="0"
                             data-y="center" data-voffset="0"
                             data-speed="600"
                             data-start="600"
                             data-easing="easeInOutQuad"
                             data-splitin="none"
                             data-splitout="none"
                             data-elementdelay="0.1"
                             data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                             data-endspeed="800"
                             data-endeasing="easeInOutQuad">
                            <span class="font3light color-bg white">לחץ להזמנת תור</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <!-- SLIDE  -->
                    <li data-transition="slidedown" data-slotamount="7" data-masterspeed="1200" data-saveperformance="off">
                        <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
                        <img data-no-retina alt="" title="" src="/dist/assets/images/bg3.jpg" data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat">
                        <!-- LAYERS -->
                        <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
                        <div class="tp-caption featured-caption-three font3bold white lft ltb tp-resizeme text-center"
                             data-x="center" data-hoffset="0"
                             data-y="center" data-voffset="0"
                             data-speed="600"
                             data-start="600"
                             data-easing="easeInOutQuad"
                             data-splitin="none"
                             data-splitout="none"
                             data-elementdelay="0.1"
                             data-endelementdelay="0.1"
                             data-endspeed="800"
                             data-endeasing="easeInOutQuad">
                            הודעות ועדכונים<span class="font3 color">המספרה סגורה בראשון הקרוב</span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tp-bannertimer tp-bottom" style="visibility: hidden !important;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</div>
<!-- end : inner-wrap -->
<!--footer-->
```

Part of my router module:

```
  RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'order', component: OrderComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
    ])
```

slider call in _layour.cshtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Baber_App</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />

    <!-- design css files - start -->
    <link href="~/dist/assets/stylesheets/animatedheaders.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Favicon
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="~/dist/assets/images/favicon.png"/>


    <!-- FONT
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600%7CMontserrat:400,700%7COpen+Sans:400,300,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- ICON FONTS
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/assets/stylesheets/ionicons.min.css">        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/assets/fonts/fonts.css">

    <!-- CSS
    –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/assets/stylesheets/isotope.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/assets/stylesheets/venobox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/assets/stylesheets/sinister.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/assets/stylesheets/animatedheaders.css">
    <!-- SLIDER REVOLUTION 4.x CSS SETTINGS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/dist/assets/rs-plugin/css/settings.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/assets/stylesheets/featured.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/assets/stylesheets/slimmenu.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/assets/stylesheets/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/assets/stylesheets/main-bg.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/assets/stylesheets/main-responsive.css">







    <!-- design css files - end -->



</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    <script src="~/dist/assets/javascripts/libs/common.js"></script>
    <script src="~/dist/assets/javascripts/libs/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/dist/assets/javascripts/libs/animatedheaders.js"></script>
    <script src="~/dist/assets/javascripts/custom/main.js"></script>
    <!-- SLIDER REVOLUTION 4.x SCRIPTS  -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/assets/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/dist/assets/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


         /******************************************
           - PREPARE PLACEHOLDER FOR SLIDER  -
         ******************************************/


         jQuery(document).ready(function () {
             jQuery('#rev_slider_3_1').show().revolution(
                 {
                     dottedOverlay: "none",
                     delay: 9000,
                     startwidth: 1200,
                     startheight: 500,
                     hideThumbs: 0,

                     thumbWidth: 100,
                     thumbHeight: 50,
                     thumbAmount: 3,


                     simplifyAll: "off",

                     navigationType: "bullet",
                     navigationArrows: "none",
                     navigationStyle: "round",

                     touchenabled: "on",
                     onHoverStop: "on",
                     nextSlideOnWindowFocus: "off",

                     swipe_threshold: 75,
                     swipe_min_touches: 1,
                     drag_block_vertical: false,



                     keyboardNavigation: "off",

                     navigationHAlign: "right",
                     navigationVAlign: "center",
                     navigationHOffset: 20,
                     navigationVOffset: 0,

                     soloArrowLeftHalign: "left",
                     soloArrowLeftValign: "center",
                     soloArrowLeftHOffset: 20,
                     soloArrowLeftVOffset: 0,

                     soloArrowRightHalign: "right",
                     soloArrowRightValign: "center",
                     soloArrowRightHOffset: 20,
                     soloArrowRightVOffset: 0,

                     shadow: 0,
                     fullWidth: "off",
                     fullScreen: "on",

                     spinner: "spinner0",

                     stopLoop: "off",
                     stopAfterLoops: -1,
                     stopAtSlide: -1,

                     shuffle: "off",


                     forceFullWidth: "off",
                     fullScreenAlignForce: "off",
                     minFullScreenHeight: "",
                     hideTimerBar: "on",
                     hideThumbsOnMobile: "off",
                     hideNavDelayOnMobile: 1500,
                     hideBulletsOnMobile: "off",
                     hideArrowsOnMobile: "off",
                     hideThumbsUnderResolution: 0,

                     fullScreenOffsetContainer: "#pseudo-header",
                     fullScreenOffset: "",
                     hideSliderAtLimit: 0,
                     hideCaptionAtLimit: 0,
                     hideAllCaptionAtLilmit: 0,
                     startWithSlide: 0
                 });
         }); //ready

    </script>          
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I see routing of your site? Maybe when you use nav link you point to the wrong component?

Comment: sure, i edited my post and published it

Comment: Is your background on your home page a slider? If so I guess you need to reappend your revolution slider and destroy it when your component is destroyed

Comment: yes it's slider. how can i destroy it?

Comment: what I did now is Home component implements OnDestroy, but what can I write there?

Comment: @lumio do u have any solution for me?

Comment: Where is your initial call for your slider?

Comment: i added the code, I put it in shared folder in _Layour.cshtml

Comment: actually it's template i bought

Comment: @lumio do you have any solution?

Comment: Sadly I don't. But my guess is, that you need to recall it everytime you are navigating to home

Comment: yes , but I don't know how to recall it..do you have an idea?

Comment: add the code to your home controller or something like that

Comment: Is there a possibility for you to share a live example host somewhere?

Comment: I can upload to github, it will help @NasirT?

Comment: Yes please do. It will help.

Comment: @NasirT, unfortunately, I did not succeed to upload to GitHub, but this is the link to upload the project, I will appreciate your help.

Comment: can you create fiddle or some demo link?

Comment: unfortunally I did not succeed to upload to fiddle also, that's the link to download https://ufile.io/sr42l

Comment: Which version of visual studios did you create this project in?

Comment: visual studio 2017

Comment: Aaah. Need to install that one. Working on it. I have VS2015. I guess a upgrade was due

Comment: okay, just if you can, if not just look on the code maybe you can find something

Comment: @NasirT did you had the opportunity to check it?

Comment: For the moment, just remove the slider component and check, whether the its behaving normal

Comment: Ok. I got your code running and what i found out is that your slider js code in the document.ready in _layout.cshtml is not being called again when you click on the home navigation via the order page. This causes the slider ul and li to not initialize with the slider classes. I am still trying to see why this is happening but what i think is that this is a routing issue as your app is using both mvc routing and also angular routing so there is some conflict in between them but need to confirm if this is the case. I am new to angular 4 with .net core so need to look at it for a solution.

Comment: Sorry for late reply and help as had a death in family and was out of city for funeral

Comment: @NasirT thank you for your time. hope for good news!

Comment: I've experienced similar things with Ionic3. I wonder if it's down to Webpack  and Sass compilation going on in the background. Do you only get this in development mode? Or in production too?

Comment: If You can use `Bootstrap`s `grid`s like: col-sm-12 etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are mixing Jquery plugins with Angular without a wrapper.

The first time the app is loaded it works because the onready is the last srcipt to run (remember that the browser executes the tags synchronously from top to bottom).

As soon as you visit the orders page Angular modifies the DOM and the slider cease to exist.

When you browse back to the homepage Angular generates the corresponding HTML (inc. the slider) but it never executes the script that configures the slider.

There are two possible solutions here, the one that will fix this quickly but it is technically wrong, and the one that is the right way to do it.

**Quick but wrong:**
Copy all inside *jQuery(document).ready(function () { });* to a new function  named, for example, *sliderSetup()*.
Implement Angular ngOnReady method in the Home Component and invoke *sliderSetup()* from there.

**Angular way:**
Search for an Angular implementation of a slider. For example:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-carousel-simple
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-owl-carousel
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-useful-swiper

DISCLAIMER: Haven't tested any of them, just Googled for some example for you.

Let me know how it goes.